# Image and file storage in block chain

Tags: private-blockchain, nodes, gas-price, ipfs

Is it possible to store a base64 image code as string in block chain?
I know we can use IPFS or Swarm as a tool to store an image or a document, but if someone gets to know about the hash anyone can tamper the image/document.
Is there any other alternative to store an image or a entire document directly to a private block chain??
I also know if i increase the gas price i can store the image but why do i need gas price in a private block which has very minimum nodes say 3-4.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. No, someone with the hash can't tamper with the image/document if it's stored in IPFS. (That's the point of the hash: it's infeasible to find another document with the same hash.) If you're using a private blockchain, you can set whatever gas price you want. With the public blockchain, you have to pay a price that will get the miners to include your transaction.